# Does OpenJPA work with SQL Server IDENTITY?

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I'm using SQL Server 2008, OpenJPA 2.2

The persistence setup is OK as `findAll()` works.

I've tried:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id = 0;
```

and to persist

```
public void persist()
{
    EntityManager em = entityManager();
    try
    {
        em.persist(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        em.close(); 
    }
}
```

The result is no exception but no data inserted.

Comment: One more thing: I am using the Eclipse -javaagent enhancement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need a transaction to commit the data?

```
try
    {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(this);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    ...
```

Comment: Wait... I think this was the issue. My transaction was in the test, which was using a diff EntityManager to the one in the Entity.